# For loop not working properly after dbRefObject

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

matchIDes[i] containing 3 different match_IDs, i want each id to access firebase and collect data against it in snapshot and return data but it is only returning data of last id.

```
for(i=0;i<=arry-1;i++) {
    matchIDes.push(response.data.MatchOdds[i].matchId);

    var dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Game').child(matchIDes[i]);

    dbRefObject.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var x = snapshot.val();
        for(i=0;i<=matchIDes.length-1;i++){
            var a = x.AllQuestion[0].EventQuestion;
            var c = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[0].GameAnswer;
            var d = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[0].odds;
            var e = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[1].GameAnswer;
            var f = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[1].odds;
            var g = x.AllQuestion[0].QuestionId;

            $("#" + matchIDes[i] + "_Quest").text(a);
            $("#" + matchIDes[i] + "_optA").text(b);
            $("#" + matchIDes[i] + "_rankA").text(c);
            $("#" + matchIDes[i] + "_optB").text(d);
            $("#" + matchIDes[i] + "_rankB").text(e);

            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-factor the code to use only one event handler:

```
var matchOddsArr = response.data.MatchOdds;
var dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Game');

dbRefObject.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnap) {
        matchOddsArr.forEach(function(matchObj) {
            var id = matchObj.matchId;
            if (childSnap.key == id) {
                var x = childSnap.val(); 
                var a = x.AllQuestion[0].EventQuestion;
                var c = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[0].GameAnswer;
                var d = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[0].odds;
                var e = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[1].GameAnswer;
                var f = x.AllQuestion[0].Options[1].odds;
                var g = x.AllQuestion[0].QuestionId;

                $("#" + id + "_Quest").text(a);
                $("#" + id + "_optA").text(b);
                $("#" + id + "_rankA").text(c);
                $("#" + id + "_optB").text(d);
                $("#" + id + "_rankB").text(e);
            };
        });
    });
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### Listen for **value** events
>
> Attaching a **value** observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to access individual children.
>
> ```
> ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
>   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>     // ...
>   });
> });
> ```

For more information, see

- [Firebase API Reference - Working with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

Comment: It Works bro, thanks alot, if you dont mind can i ask you how did this code works? i'm a bit new in this realtime-firebase technology with angularjs, would appreciate your explanation :)

Comment: Added reference to the Firebase Docs.